# Facebook.init on flash FacebookGraphAPI can't connect

Tags: flash, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an Flash AS3 app using FacebookGraphAPI, and today 05/09/2012 the app can't connect with Facebook, I'm have no idea what to do.

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the same problem as here [Facebook AS3 api log in box did work, a day later it does not](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10518388/facebook-as3-api-log-in-box-did-work-a-day-later-it-does-not/10522626#10522626)

1.- If you are using GraphAPI_Web_1_8_1.swc delete it.

2.- Download the modified graph api from [here](http://ederchrono.com/blog/srcfiles/GRAPHAPI_mod.rar)

3.- Paste those folders on your librarys, if you had the facebook folder overwrite it.

4.- Publish your project.

This problem started when facebook changed its file connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js in a way that all the calls made from the as3 file "FacebookJSBridge.as" must be changed from "FB.JSON" to just "JSON".

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug today in the Javascript SDK
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/420667497951980
https://developers.facebook.com/live_status

Here is an already answered question:
[Facebook AS3 api log in box did work, a day later it does not](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10518388/facebook-as3-api-log-in-box-did-work-a-day-later-it-does-not)